# How to combine multiple update GORM MySql queries into 1?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have a MySQL table containing 4 columns

```
(A(primary key, int), B(string), C(string), D(string)).
```

I want to run an update query finding row using A, where I can update data of 1, 2, or all 3  columns(B, C, D).
I get the data from the front-end in JSON format. Currently, I am checking the length of strings I get in input, and if they are >0, I update those columns one by one. So in the worst case, I will be running 3 SQL updates.
Is there a way to do this in 1 SQL query using GORM, and Golang?

```
Example JSON structure
{
A: 23,
B: "word1",
D: "word2"
}
```

In this case, I only want to update columns B and D.

I will unmarshal this using a Golang structure which will be of the form

```
type rating struct{
    A int,
    B string,
    C string,
    D string
        }
```

So in Golang value of C will be an empty string.

```
var rating_var rating
if len(rating_var.B)>0{
       db.Model(&ratings).where("A=?",rating_var.A).Update(map[struct]interface{}{"B": rating_var.B})
        }

if len(rating_var.C)>0{
       db.Model(&ratings).where("A=?",rating_var.A).Update(map[struct]interface{}{"C": rating_var.C})
        }

if len(rating_var.D)>0{
       db.Model(&ratings).where("A=?",rating_var.A).Update(map[struct]interface{}{"D": rating_var.D})
        }
```

Is there a way to do this in 1 SQL query using GORM, and Golang?

Comment: How do you get the inputs here? Can you cache those inputs on front-end/back-end so that you can run one SQL query? Gorm is a driver and not opinionated. I believe if you can not cache the input's you will have to run 3 SQL updates.

Comment: What is I get in input with length >0 is the input of one field? You process that field to create 3 more values? What is the Json structure here? Can you add that too

Comment: @ShaileshSuryawanshi I am new to Golang, currently, I am getting these values in JSON format through Postman to the backend(Golang).

Comment: will `UPDATE table_name SET B = json.B, C = json.C WHERE A = json.A;` this SQL query work? If that is the case do you want help with building this sql query for Gorm? https://gorm.io/docs/update.html this document might help

Comment: @ShaileshSuryawanshi If I run this query C will be set to empty string. I don't want to update a column if I don't get any corresponding value in JSON.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235269/discussion-between-shailesh-suryawanshi-and-soumil-kanwal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to build a Model according to your conditions first. Use that model to run only one SQL query. Check the complete example on playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ewPPw4wmIyk).

Note that gorm will take care of some missing fields. Now if the `rating.C` is blank, gorm will not update the value of `c column` in record.

```golang
        rating := Rating{
                A: 1,
                B: "b1",
                D: "d2",
        }

        var toUpdate RatingModel
        if len(rating.B) > 0 {
                toUpdate.B = rating.B
        }

        if len(rating.C) > 0 {
                toUpdate.C = rating.C
        }

        if len(rating.D) > 0 {
                toUpdate.D = rating.D
        }
        db.Model(&toUpdate).Where("A=?", rating.A).Updates(toUpdate)
```

I would suggest using structs over map. Go is strongly typed language thus using structs is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Updates` to update multiple fields.

```
db.Model(&user).Updates(User{Name: "hello", Age: 18, Active: false})

db.Model(&ratings).where("A=?",rating_var.A).Updates(map[struct]interface{}{"B": rating_var.B, "C": rating_var.C})
```

[Updates](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Updates-multiple-columns)